# List Android with two childs in one row

Tags: android, listview, expandable

Have an expandable listview with two childs in different rows.

I would like to know if I can put two childs at the same row. Something like that

```
++++++++++++++++

+Parent 1+

++++++++++++++++

+Child 1+++Child 2+ 

++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Just wrap add the two Child views into a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Your list adapters getView() logic should populate each before returning the new layout wrapping them.

Comment: Sorry but because i am new in android programming can you help me more and be more specific. Thanks!!

Comment: There is a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row).